# Rails Active Record Query - display projects to project creators/members

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have three tables: `User` through devise, `Project`, and `ProjectUser`.

A `User` can be part of many `Project` through `ProjectUser`'s table. How can I query so `Project`'s index action displays Projects that the current user has created and is a member of?

Let's say I have three projects and two team members:

- User 1 created and is a member of Project A
- User 2 created and is a member of Project B
- User 2 created and is a member of Project C
- User 1 is a member of Project C

When I'm signed in as:

- User 1, I should be able to see both Project A and C.
- User 2, I should be able to see both Project B and C.

---

Here are my models, controllers, and schema:

*projects_controller.rb*

```
@projects = current_user.projects.joins(:project_users).distinct.order("created_at DESC")
```

*project.rb*

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :project_users
  has_many :users, through: :project_users
end
```

*user.rb*

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :project_users
  has_many :projects, through: :project_users
end
```

*project_user.rb*

```
class ProjectUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project
end
```

*schema.rb*

```
create_table "project_users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "user_id", null: false
    t.bigint "project_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["project_id"], name: "index_project_users_on_project_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_project_users_on_user_id"
end
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the query that works for my case

`Project.joins(:project_users).where(project_users: {user_id: current_user.id}`

Answer (score 0):

I think that this should work for you

```
@projects = current_user.projects.distinct.order("created_at DESC")
```

*You don't need the: *joins(:project_users)**

> For more info about the has_many :through Association:
> https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Comment: Thanks, Toni. This only displays projects where the current user has created, but not those the current user is a member of.

Comment: You need to create the members as a new record on project_users. If you wan't to know who is the creator of the project or the admin, (Make sure that in the Project model there's no prop user_id. You don't need that.) Make sure that this is correct. The code that you added in the question it's ok. And you should be able to make the call current_user.projects and display all the records that appear in ProjectUser model.

Comment: If you wan't, post in a comment the git repo and i take a look ! :)